# can not use grunt command in windows DOS

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

I have successfully installed nodejs in my Windows system , and was able to use the node - v and NPM - v command.And my successful use of NPM - g grunt - cli command to install grunt,but when I input the grunt commands in other project But warned no global variables of grunt, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I installed Express and Node on Windows I think I might have had to go into the Control Panel -> System Properties area (Advanced Tab) and append some things to my path.  Environment Variables -> System Variables -> Path

I appended all these things somewhere along the way:
C:\Ruby193\bin
c:\python27
c:\python27\scripts
C:\Program Files\nodejs
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd

Comment: I also note that many UNIX-style commands that use single quotes need to be converted to double quotes, like when using the git command.